# Merge two divs inside a div with responsive feature

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am making a responsive form in asp.net. I want to combine two divs with responsive feature. here are the details [Out put of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSeOx.jpg)

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.txtBoxLeft {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #5250fb;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #908fff;
  color: white;
}
.txtBoxRight {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px #5250fb;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
.txtBoxRight:focus {
  border: solid 1px #908fff;
  background-color: #f3f4ff;
}
.txtBoxRight-1 input[type="text"] {
  width: 70%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.txtBoxRight-7 input[type="text"] {
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="txtBoxLeft">CNIC #</div>
  <div class="txtBoxRight-1">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCNIC" CssClass="txtBoxRight" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="txtBoxLeft">Drop 1-ID</div>
  <div class="txtBoxRight-7">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDrop1ID" Class="txtBoxRight" runat="server" ToolTip="ID"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have attached the code and output. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

set container width 100% , then give every controls want to be responsive width percentage % as you need ,
for mobile responsive  use this code

@media (max-width:768px) {
    .myclass {
        expand each input to 100%
    }
}

Comment: When I the add the width:100% into the container class. I receive the same problem as shown in the previous picture (Which i have attached in my question).